# Git configure order in which files are merged

Tags: git

Our repository contains multiple files that are source code and one file that is a build artefact (compiled apiary blueprint for example).

There is a build script I can configure as merge driver for this file, but it fails if the source is not yet merged (or at least it builds from the merge state, which is not correct). Is there a way to tell git in what order it should try to merge files? There is a `-O<orderfile>` for `git-diff`, but that does not seem to be applied to `git-merge`.

Comment: The thing is apiary requires the file to be named `apiary.apib` so I can't solve  it by renaming the file.

I could create a file like `zzzz` and every time the artefact is build, populate it with a random content to trigger merge and configure the merge for this file instead (to build the apiary blueprint), configuring the origin `apiary.apib` file as `-merge`. It would work I but don't like the idea of having such a hacky file in a repo.

Comment: "There is a `-O<orderfile>` for `git-diff`, but that does not seem to be applied to `git-merge`.": it will with Git 2.11+ (Q4 2016)! See [my edited and revised answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32153611/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update October 2016, for Git 2.11+ (Q4 2016)

> There is a `-O<orderfile>` for `git-diff`, but that does not seem to be applied to `git-merge`.

There is now, but for `git mergetool`:

See [commit 654311b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/654311bf6ee0fbf530c088271c2c76d46f31f82d) (08 Oct 2016), and [commit 57937f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57937f70a09c12ef484c290865dac4066d207c9c), [commit 08221e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08221e3fa27396aca30cb539f006f78636782951), [commit 8827b3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8827b3a8873ebfad79b324d6134c1ec4bbea5f06) (07 Oct 2016) by [David Aguilar (`davvid`)](https://github.com/davvid).
Helped-by: [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5b4c45a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b4c45af0cb5cea7b26e2fb5464038f7663f5800), 17 Oct 2016)</sup>

> ### `mergetool`: honor `-O<orderfile>`
>
> Teach `mergetool` to pass "`-O<orderfile>`" down to `git diff` when
>   specified on the command-line.

The [`git mergetool` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/654311bf6ee0fbf530c088271c2c76d46f31f82d/Documentation/git-mergetool.txt#L82-L87) now includes:

```
-O<orderfile>:
```

> Process files in the order specified in the `<orderfile>`, which has one shell glob pattern per line.
>   This overrides the `diff.orderFile` configuration variable.
>   To cancel `diff.orderFile`, use `-O/dev/null`.

Note: the orderfile format is only documented in Git 2.12.

See [commit 874444b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/874444b70451879d5b9b7e288e5c4e711c4a87ac), [commit 1a5fccc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a5fccc0c26b4a8abafd85a73558022e65f6f8cf) (15 Jan 2017) by [Richard Hansen (`rhansen`)](https://github.com/rhansen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 831bd5e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/831bd5e775ad5225f2a98eba738f69148cd50e0a), 23 Jan 2017)</sup>

---

Original answer August 2015

It seems the issue comes from the modifications done to the merge driver script, *in addition* of modifications to other files.

When you are merging your branch, the merge driver script isn't yet merged itself.

Why not update your merge driver script in a separate, dedicated branch, and merge that branch first.
Then merge your dev branch second.

An alternative approach would also uses a wrapper, as the [OP Mikulas Dite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326257/mikulas-dite) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149151/git-configure-order-in-which-files-are-merged/32153611#comment52197408_32153611):

> Turns out it's really as simple a creating a custom merge wrapper, leaving the build artefact as `-merge`.
>   The wrapper runs `git merge`, and if there are no other unresolved files other than the artefact, run the build script.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not quite sure I follow. The issue is definitely not with merging the driver, it's not even located in the repo as its more of a proof of concept now. Neither are the attributes, they are for the time being local only and stored in `.git/info/attributes`.

Comment: @MikulasDite OK, but the idea remains: in term of merge order, isolate what you want to be merge first in its own branch, merge that branch first, then merge the rest from the usual branch.

Comment: Right, but that defeats the purpose, I wanted to simplify the process. I mean I can run the build script after all dependencies are merged manually. Sure it's a trifle all right but one I would love to get rid of.

Comment: @MikulasDite agree, but if your merge script does those two merge in the right order, you won't have any more issue. Since there is no ordering during a merge, that would be the workaround I would recommend.

Comment: Oh, took me a while, but I get it. Turns out it's really as simple a creating a custom merge wrapper, leaving the build artefact as `-merge`. The wrapper runs `git merge`, and if there are no other unresolved files other than the artefact, run the build script. Now if only I could get this to work with `git-rebase` as well.
Can you please update the answer to reflect this discussion so I can accpet it?

Comment: @MikulasDite I have edited the answer to include your comment for more visibility.